# Is the FC-center of a finitely generated group itself finitely generated?

Tags: group-theory, finitely-generated

For a group $G$, its FC-Center $FC(G)$ is the subgroup consisting of the elements of $G$ which have a finite conjugacy class (in $G$).

Let $G$ be a finitely generated group. Is $FC(G)$ necessarily finitely generated as well?

In case the answer is no, what if we assume further that $G$ is finitely presented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example I gave in my answer to [Center of a finitely generated group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109725) is a finitely generated group in which the centre is not finitely generated. In fact $Z(G) = {\rm FC}(G)$ in that example, so the answer to your first question is no.

In a comment, Arturo Magidin gave a reference for an example of a finitely presented group in which $Z(G)$ is not finitely generated. You would need to look at the example and check whether it also has ${\rm FC}(G)$ not finitely generated. Perhaps $Z(G)={\rm FC}(G)$ in that example too, but I don't know!

Comment: Yes, FC equals the center in Abels' group (the group given by Arturo). This holds in any subgroup of $GL_n$ whose Zariski closure is connected.